# If ARRAY value, use other ARRAY value

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{
    "Group": [
        {
            "name": "HolderOne",
            "operators": [
                {
                    "username": "ken",
                    "status": 3
                },
     .....etc.....
```

Hi all,

I've succesfully pulled data out of my JSON feed thanks the help on SO...but...scratching my head now.

By using `print_r($obj->....)` I am able to extract all information from my feed BUT what I want to be able to do is...

**From above, if the value of username is 'ken' then only display the associated status 3.**

I think it could be using the value the print_r assigns each `Array(?)` e.g. above would be `[0]` - now I don't know what the value would be so can I grab the `[n]` value for each username to display the status?

I am slightly outside my comfort zone here...not sure if it's a PHP or JSON problem for a start.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach($obj->Group as $group)
{
    foreach($group->operators as $operator)
    {
       if($operator->username == "ken")
       {
           echo $operator->status;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it worked then how about an up vote and accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt solution.  I've tried this and I get *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in *

Comment: The only way I could get the data out was via `print_r($obj->callCentres->name->operators[0]->username);`

Comment: ok, well that doesn't match up with the sample json you gave in the question ;)  Anyway, just change the code so that is has the inner foreach iterating over $obj->callCentres->name->operators and eliminate the outer foreach.

Comment: `<?php
    foreach($obj->Group->name->operators[0] as $operator)
    {
       if($operator->username == "ken")
       {
           echo $operator->status;
       }
    }

?>`  Still doesn't work :-(  I get: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `  Sorry I should add I changed the coding befiore - so for you answer, I did replace `group` with `callCentres` properly

Comment: Take the [0] off the end of operators.  As you have it you are trying to iterate over the first item, not the array itself.

Comment: :o( `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..`   using `<?php foreach($obj->Group->name->operators as $operator) { if($operator->username == "ken") { echo $operator->status; } } ?>`